# Cassandra not having my data as expected

Tags: cassandra

I am preparing my data(52GB) for performing some range queries on my local machine.

My data is in BSON file. I am converting it to spark rdd/dataFrame and write it Cassandra for quick range queries.

The data I had doesn't have any unique way of ranges to select, so I added a `column(idx)` in the rdd dataframe that is unique by calling `monotically_increase()`, and writing it to Cassandra.

But Cassandra, is overwriting that idx values to something very big.

```
train_df = train_df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())

try:
#"CREATE TABLE t (pk int, t int, v text, s text, PRIMARY KEY (pk, t));
        create_table = "CREATE TABLE train ( idx BIGINT, cid BIGINT, img BLOB, PRIMARY KEY (idx, cid));"                                        
        session.execute(create_table)
    except:
        print("create table train failed")
    train_df.write\
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .mode('append') \
        .option("table", "train") \
        .option("keyspace", "komal")\
        .save()

    Any query indexing above 5000 is returing empty list
    query = "select * from train where idx > 5000 and idx <= 6000 ALLOW FILTERING;"
    result = session.execute(query, timeout=50000000)

    result.current_rows
    []
```

Can some one help on how to add a column in Cassandra that can be unique so I run a range queries?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to select a range of partition keys (in your case `idx` is the partition key). This is not the way to do things in cassandra as the partition key "selects" the node where cassandra actually stores your data. Your query will involve scanning all cluster nodes - and that may be painfully slow.

If you need range queries - you can do those only efficient inside a partition. In your example `t` is a cluster column and defines the order on all entries in that partition (`idx`). On disk data is stored sorted (hence sstables = sorted string tables) so queries for a range are efficient here.